# Some videos have no audio at Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: audio, ubuntu-18.04

I am facing a strange issue. I can hear audio from youtube and other downloaded video files from my ubuntu. Recently, I have bought some courses from udemy. Surprisingly, there is no audio when I play those videos on my browser. I have changed the browser but no help. I tried with chrome & firefox. I even downloaded the video to my pc and play from that. Video is running but there is no audio! I don't understand what's the problem as other videos is running with audio.

This is the property of the video from where I am NOT getting any sound.

[image]

And This is the property of the video from where I am getting sound.

[image]

This is the screenshot of my sound setting:

[image]

Note: videos from udemy is running correctly (with audio) at windows 10 & ubuntu OS in my other pc.

So far, I've tried with these commands. But, still the issue exists.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

============== **Update** ===================

I found the problem! Cable of my headphone is so small that can't reach to my ear if I directly insert it at speaker port. That's why, I use an extension cable. But, with the cable I can't hear audio from udemy's video. Without cable, I can hear it. But, it's still strange as I can hear audio from other video's (except udemy's videos) with the extension cable! Any solution for it without changing the cable?

[image]

Comment: Since the audio codecs are the same, it seems like a bug. If the other PC has an older version of Ubuntu, I would suggest reporting this issue as a bug on Launchpad. But if it's the same version, then that's weird... I can't explain that.

Comment: I checked at the same version of Ubuntu, that's why it's weird!

Comment: OK, do you have any packages installed on the other Ubuntu that are not installed on this machine?

Comment: Can't remember any special package that have been installed on the other Ubuntu..

Comment: You can find the process ID of the application which is not playing audio and type pmap and then the process ID to see all the library files that are loaded. Then do the same thing on the Ubuntu that works. In this way you can find any libraries that are missing or not being used.

Comment: @RobinGreen I found the problem. Can you please read the Update portion of my post?

Comment: It's not physically possible for your cable to be the problem. It's an analog cable.